# How can I replace my Verizon FIOS Router?

Tags: internet, fios

I am currently renting a Actiontec MI424WR Verizon FiOS Router. I'd like to get rid of this and stop renting, but as SidneySM informed me in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/49963/why-did-verizon-hook-fios-up-with-ethernet-and-coax), the coax connection is needed to create a MoCA network so that the set top boxes can have their TV guide and on demand features.

Is there some type of COAX to Ethernet device I can use so I don't need Verizon's router anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This FAQ](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/verizonfios/3.0_Networking) is a really good reference for dealing with various FiOS networking issues.  The bottom line is that if you have TV through FiOS, you simply can't get rid of the provided router completely.  However, you *can* augment the provided router with your own and depending on how complex you want to get, the ActionTec can essentially act as a dedicated router just for the set-top boxes.

[This option](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/15993) is the one I'm planning on going with once my FiOS order gets setup.

Comment: Thanks for the link. So there is no device which will act like the ActionTec router but only perform the MoCA network?

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to user the Verizon Router.   The ActionTec is a piece of garbage.

I use my own TPlink Gigabit router running ww-ddrt

you will need to come out of your router to this little device that Verizon provides for the guide to work on your set top boxes.    and RG6 cable from that little device back to the ONT.

Been running this way since day one.

Answer (score 0):

purchased two dxn-220 dlink units today.  set one for 1000 mhz and the other for 1150mhz.  plugged the 1000 mhz unit into the wan of my router and plugged ther 1150 unit into the lan.  I used a splitter to connect coax from the ont to both units.  The important thing to do is to release the ip from the actiontec before connecting the dxn-220.  everything works like lightning. go here for help
http://www.dslreports.com/faq/16793